# trouble appending table elements dynamically while looping through json

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

I'm pulling in data in json format, looping through the json and creating tables dynamically. But for some reason, the code seems to automatically close my table after the first line. Anyone know how to fix this please?

jquery:

```
$.ajax({  //fetch the stock data from dB
        url: "php/data.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            var objCandidates = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
            var old_office = ""; new_office = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < objCandidates.length; i++) {
                new_office = objCandidates[i].contest;
                if (new_office != old_office) {
                    $('body').append("</tbody></table><table class='z-depth-3 striped'><thead><tr><th colspan='4'>" + new_office + "</th></thead><tbody><tr><td>" + objCandidates[i].candidate + "</td><td>" + objCandidates[i].tot_votes + "</td><td>" + objCandidates[i].perc_votes + "</td></tr>");
                } 
                else {
                    $('body').append("<tr><td>" + objCandidates[i].candidate + "</td><td>" + objCandidates[i].tot_votes + "</td><td>" + objCandidates[i].perc_votes + "</td></tr>");
                }
                old_office = new_office;
            }   

        },
        error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
        }
    });
```

The output looks like:

```
<table class="z-depth-3 striped"><thead><tr><th colspan="4">Judge of the Superior Court (Vote For 4)</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Jane Doe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
<tr><td>John Doe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Richard Roe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Steve Soe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Mike Moe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<table class="z-depth-3 striped"><thead><tr><th colspan="4">Another Judge of the Superior Court (Vote For 4)</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Janet Doe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>...
```

Comment: can you post what html you want?

Comment: I want the tables to end after the last row:

Comment: <table class="z-depth-3 striped"><thead><tr><th colspan="4">Judge of the Superior Court (Vote For 4)</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Jane Doe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
<tr><td>John Doe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Richard Roe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Steve Soe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Mike Moe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<table class="z-depth-3 striped"><thead><tr><th colspan="4">Another Judge of the Superior Court (Vote For 4)</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Janet Doe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Sorry -- 
<table class="z-depth-3 striped"><thead><tr><th colspan="4">Judge of the Superior Court (Vote For 4)</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Jane Doe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
<tr><td>John Doe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Richard Roe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Steve Soe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Mike Moe</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>

(next table)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using inline text with the script you can define a template with some palceholders for json values for example

```
<div id="mytemplate">
</tbody><table><tr>
<td>name</td>
<td>Id</td>
<td>whateverplacehodler</td></tr></tbody>
</div>
```

and ready the template with jquery like this

```
var myTemplate=$("#mytemplate").html();
$.ajax({  //fetch the stock data from dB
        url: "php/data.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            var objCandidates = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
            var old_office = ""; new_office = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < objCandidates.length; i++) {
                new_office = objCandidates[i].contest;
                if (new_office != old_office) {
                    var mynewtml=myTemplate;
                    //No Start replacing The Place Holders with Your JsonData
                    $('body').append(mynewtml);
                } 
                else {
                 //Do the Same But With Another Template If You Want
                }
                old_office = new_office;
            }   

        },
        error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
        }
    });
```

this Way You Can Have Clean js Code And Easily Detect Problems With Your Template Html Template

Answer (score 0):

@Hassan Elsherbiny was close. I used:

```
$.ajax({  
        url: "php/data.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            var objCandidates = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
            var old_office = ""; new_office = "";
            var $newtable;
            var tableNum = -1;

            for (var i = 0; i < objCandidates.length; i++) {
                new_office = objCandidates[i].contest;

                if (new_office != old_office) { //if we're on to a different race
                    //get ready to start a new table
                    tableNum++;
                    //start a new table
                    $newtable = "<table class='z-depth-3 striped' id='table" + tableNum +"'><thead><tr><th colspan='4'></th></thead><tbody></tbody></table>";
                    $('body').append( $newtable );

                    //put the new race into the table header
                    $('#table' + tableNum + ' thead tr th').html(new_office + " <small>" + percPrecinctsReporting + "% precincts reporting</small>");
                } 
                //put the candidate into the table
                if ( new_office.indexOf("Referendum") > -1 ) {
                    $('#table' + tableNum + ' tbody').append("<tr><td width='90%'>" + objCandidates[i].candidate + "</td><td>" + objCandidates[i].tot_votes + "</td><td>" + objCandidates[i].perc_votes + "</td></tr>");
                } else {
                    $('#table' + tableNum + ' tbody').append("<tr><td width='90%'>" + objCandidates[i].candidate + " (" + objCandidates[i].party + ")</td><td>" + objCandidates[i].tot_votes + "</td><td>" + objCandidates[i].perc_votes + "</td></tr>");
                }

                old_office = new_office;

            }   

        },
        error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
        }
    });
```